# No feature is added to VectorLayer while trying to add programmatically

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I'm trying to add some `VectorLayers` programmatically to my map after some data is fetched from the database and filesystem. The problem I'm facing is that although the data and `VectorLayer` are added to the map, the source features are not loaded. After everything runs, if I `console.log(this.map.getLayers())` I can see the layer added there, but if I `console.log(addedLayer.getSource().getFeatures())` the result is an empty array.

- OpenLayers v6.1.1

**My code**

```js
this.storage.get("my_layers").then(layers => {
    if (layers) {
        let parsedLayers = JSON.parse(layers);

        // Loop through the layers
        for (let prop in parsedLayers) {
            let file_location = parsedLayers[prop]['file_location'];
            let filename = file_location.split('/').pop();

            let newVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
                source: new VectorSource ({
                    format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'})
                }),
                style: this.styleArea('rgba(11, 102, 35, 1)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', 2), //Returns green with black border
                name: parsedLayers[prop]['layer_id'],
                visible: true
            });                 

            this.file.readAsText(this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'projects/' + this.projectId + '/layers/', filename)
            .then(layer_file => {               
                newVectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(JSON.parse(layer_file));
                this.map.addLayer(newVectorLayer);
                console.log(newVectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures()); // Returns an empty array                        
            });             
        }
    }
});
```

[`this.storage`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage), [`this.file`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) and `this.map` is the map itself.

I also tried to add the features this way, as [seen here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255806/127063), but got the same results:

```js
newVectorLayer.getSource().getFormat().readFeatures(JSON.parse(layer_file));
```

I don't know if this is the best way to load a local file and add to source, so please let me know. First I tried with the built-in `url` option from [`VectorSource`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html), but it uses a XHR loader that is blocked by CORS when trying to load from `file://...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a separate variable for the source format, as seen [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230946/127063):

```js
...
let newVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource ({}),
    style: this.styleArea('rgba(11, 102, 35, 1)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', 2), // Returns green with black border
    name: parsedLayers[prop]['layer_id'],
    visible: true
});                 

this.file.readAsText(this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'projects/' + this.projectId + '/layers/', filename).then(layer_file => {
    let format = new GeoJSON({
        featureProjection:"EPSG:3857",
        dataProjection:"EPSG:31982"
    });
    newVectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(format.readFeatures(layer_file)); // Don't needed to parse here
    this.map.addLayer(newVectorLayer);          
});
...
```